# Parsing encoded tags in Ruby XML document using Nokogiri and regex

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, parsing, nokogiri

I am trying to parse XML with tags embedded in tags, like this one using Nokigiri and Ruby:

```
<seg>Trennmesser <ph>&lt;I.FIGREF ITEM=&quot;3&quot; FORMAT=&quot;PARENTHESIS&quot;&gt;</ph><bpt i="1">&lt;I.FIGTARGET TARGET=&quot;CIADDAJA&quot;&gt;</bpt><ept i="1">&lt;/I.FIGREF&gt;</ept></seg>
```

In this case I would only need the word "Trennmesser" not within the embedded tags.

In this second example:

```
<seg>Hilfsmittel <ph>&lt;F34@Z7@Lge&gt;</ph>X <ph>&lt;F0&gt;</ph>= 0,5mm zwischen    Beschleunigerwalze <ph>&lt;F34@Z7@Lge&gt;</ph>D<ph>&lt;F0&gt;</ph> und Trennmesser schieben.</seg>
```

The words within the closed `/ph` and open `ph` tags are also interesting, so the regex would need to extract the string "`Hilfsmittel 0,5mm zwischen Beschleunigerwalze und Trennmesser schieben.`" and discard everything else.

I have also uploaded a part of the document here:
http://pastebin.com/Q8CdnASz

Answer (score 1):

Try this in irb

```
require 'nokogiri'
x = Nokogiri::XML.parse('<seg>Hilfsmittel <ph>&lt;F34@Z7@Lge&gt;</ph>X <ph>&lt;F0&gt;</ph>= 0,5mm zwischen    Beschleunigerwalze <ph>&lt;F34@Z7@Lge&gt;</ph>D<ph>&lt;F0&gt;</ph> und Trennmesser schieben.</seg>')
x.xpath('//seg').children.reject {|x| x.element?}.join {|x| x.content}
```

for me this outputs

```
=> "Hilfsmittel X = 0,5mm zwischen    Beschleunigerwalze D und Trennmesser schieben."
```

The idea here is that we iterate over the children of the `<seg>` tag, rejecting the ones that are elements themselves (`<ph>`), which should leave only the content elements.  Take the resultant array, and join the content elements together as one string.

Note that the output is slightly different than you described, because there's an additional `D` and `X` in between two of the tags.

Answer (score 1):

The content inside the `<ph>` tags has been encoded to preserve the reserved characters `<` and `>`.

A clean way to deal with this is to let Nokogiri reparse those chunks back into XML:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML('<seg>Trennmesser <ph>&lt;I.FIGREF ITEM=&quot;3&quot; FORMAT=&quot;PARENTHESIS&quot;&gt;</ph><bpt i="1">&lt;I.FIGTARGET TARGET=&quot;CIADDAJA&quot;&gt;</bpt><ept i="1">&lt;/I.FIGREF&gt;</ept></seg>')

ph = Nokogiri::XML::DocumentFragment.parse(doc.at('seg ph').content)
puts ph.to_xml
```

Which outputs the following node, showing Nokogiri recreated that fragment correctly:

```
<I.FIGREF ITEM="3" FORMAT="PARENTHESIS"/>
```

For extracting the text inside the `<seg>` tag:

```
doc.at('//seg/text()').text
=> "Trennmesser "
```

When dealing with HTML or XML, it's never good to presuppose that regex will be the best path to extracting something. Both HTML and XML are too irregular and "flexible" (where flexible means it's often irritatingly malformed or defined in totally unique and unexpected ways).

To get the full content inside the `<seg>` tag in the second question:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML('<seg>Hilfsmittel <ph>&lt;F34@Z7@Lge&gt;</ph>X <ph>&lt;F0&gt;</ph>= 0,5mm zwischen    Beschleunigerwalze <ph>&lt;F34@Z7@Lge&gt;</ph>D<ph>&lt;F0&gt;</ph> und Trennmesser schieben.</seg>')

seg = Nokogiri::XML::DocumentFragment.parse(doc.at('seg').content)
puts seg.content
```

Which outputs:

```
Hilfsmittel @Z7@Lge>X = 0,5mm zwischen    Beschleunigerwalze @Z7@Lge>D und Trennmesser schieben.
```